# How can I use Powershell to add roles & features to a windows server?

Tags: windows, powershell

While I know there is a powershell command called `Install-WindowsFeature` I'd like to find out how to translate the GUI interface for each "checkbox" I select, in addition to the prompts where the GUI says additional features need to be selected to "install" a specified checkbox.

In other words, I'd like to be able to capture the features I install with the GUI and be able to script it.

Comment: you might be looking for `-IncludeAllSubFeature`and  `-IncludeManagementTools` parameters of `Install-WindowsFeature`